# CodeIgniter insert two rows instead one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an issue with CodeIgniter. For some reason it insert two rows in database instead one.

Below is code from **model**:

```
/**
* Add new fuel
*/
public function addNewFuel($id = NULL, $data) {
    if ($id) {
        var_dump('TEST');
        $data = array(
           'price' => '333' ,
           'fuel' => 'dizelka' ,
           'petrol_id' => '66'
        );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';

        $this->db->insert('prices', $data);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        $this->db->insert('prices_archive',$data);

        return;
    }

}
```

And here is output:

```
string(4) "TEST"
Array
(
    [price] => 333
    [fuel] => dizelka
    [petrol_id] => 66
)
```

EDIT:

This is code from **controller** which calls model's function:

```
function addnewfuel() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $fuel = $this->input->post('fuel');
        $price = $this->input->post('price');
        $addNewFuel = array('fuel' => $fuel, 'price' => $price);
        $data['addNewFuel'] = $this->Adminarea_model->addNewFuel($id,$addNewFuel);
        $data['getFuels'] = $this->Adminarea_model->getFuels();
        $data['getPetrolNameByID'] = $this->Adminarea_model->getPetrolNameByID();
        $data['getPetrolInformation'] = $this->Adminarea_model->getPetrolInformation();
        $this->load->view('admin/edit', $data);
    } else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

For some reasons in a table 'prices' I'm getting two rows with same data, and I really don't have idea why that happens.

Thanks

Comment: Your defo not loading the page twice? Put a unique constraint on fuel to make it throw an error when the second row is being written this should help you spot where it is happening

Comment: @MikeMiller I will check that. And I'm 99% sure that page isn't loaded twice. I'm getting this in database for one insertion http://prntscr.com/6hod61

Comment: provide more code, how is this PHP being run? theres gotta be something else thats making it do that

Comment: echo out `$this->db->last_query()` after`$this->db->insert('prices', $data);` and what query you got.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Hey, here is query I got with that command: 
INSERT INTO `prices` (`price`, `fuel`, `petrol_id`) VALUES ('333', 'dizelka', '66')

Comment: @CodeGodie I edited my post with piece of code from controller which call function $this->Adminarea_model->addNewFuel($id,$addNewFuel); in model.

Comment: I see that you have `var_dump('test')` in your model method, how many times do you see this dumping?

Comment: Only once. I know what you are asking. You think how code for insertion data to database is called twice, but it isn't. I have very good knowledge in web development and you can't forget on that things. That isn't definitely problem, but I really don't know what is. 

I will try to create a custom controller and custom model and just call it with a specific link for testing purposes and than I will get back here with a results. @CodeGodie

Comment: sure thing buddy, just trying to help. good luck.

Comment: This query should not insert two data.some how insert query executing twice from here or there.I have suggestion to debug it.write `die()` after your insert query and check database if it is inserting twice?if still it inserting twice write `die()` before query and check if it inserts once.Hope you will get Idea. Also let me know what happened die after and before.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Thank you! When I put die() before insert it doesn't insert anything. When I put it after insert it insert only one row. I will investigate Today how this function is called twice and I will get back to you guys with informations. 
Thanks

Comment: So this function inserts once.Either this function is called twice or another insert query is called from somewhere.

Comment: can you show your view code? is there any validation function call?

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting data both from controller as well as from model.

remove this from model, hope it ill solve the problem. Thanks

```
 $data = array(
       'price' => '333' ,
       'fuel' => 'dizelka' ,
       'petrol_id' => '66'
    );
```